# No driver for Panasonic workio dp-c323 photocopier

Tags: printing

I cant seem to find a Linux driver for the Panasonic workio dp-c323 photocopier. Is there a way to port the ppd infor from windows to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

According to it's specifications this office machine supports PCL6 printer language, it can support PostScript 3 with an optional module.

If you have the PostScript 3 module it should be possible to use the PPD file provided by Panasonic to get this printer working (recommended), if you don't have that module you can still select one of the Generic PCL6 drivers included with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the message I will give it a go. I will see if the generic pcl6 driver works.